# htaccess Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Im trying to rewrite my existing url from `http://localhost/website/article.php?id=5` to `http://localhost/website/article/5` hence my htaccess code

```
RewriteBase /website/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule article/([a-zA-Z0-9@.-])? article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

What I get is 
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/website/article/css/bootstrap.min.css".`

It appears that *article* is added to the file's url, redirecting even the file directories.

The real url should be `"http://localhost/website/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Im quite new to htaccess and trying to create my own by copying from existing ones

**REVISION**

My actual problem is that my resources url is being renamed as well. I've eliminated lines of codes down to 2 lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule article/([0-9@.-])  article.php?id=$1
```

but now the resources is being redirected to non existent `http://localhost/website/article/js/main.js`  instead of `http://localhost/website/js/main.js`

Comment: Maybe you need to put `/css/bootstrap.min.css` into your markup `link` element?

Comment: you do know, the Conditions are only used for the first rewriterule? The article rewrite rule is always excecuted

Answer (score 2):

Check the URLs in the main HTML file; I suspect the browser is requesting the wrong URL before it gets to the rewrite rules.  If you have relative URLs like `<script src="js/main.js">`, then in the non-rewritten version the browser will resolve this to `http://localhost/website/js/main.js`, but in the rewritten version it will resolve to `http://localhost/website/article/js/main.js`, because from the browser's perspective the HTML file is in the directory `http://localhost/website/article/`, so it resolves relative to that.  If this is the issue, you can change it to `src="/website/js/main.js"` or `src="../js/main.js"`.

Answer (score 0):

Add rewrite condition to exclude static files from being rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer starting the rewrite rules with the lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  - [L]
```

It will exclude all exsisting files (-f) and directories (-d) from being rewritten. including the .php files and css files